# Capital Gains Tax - rented my flat at no real profit for a number of years

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

I have been letting my home to lodgers on and off for a few years to friends for no profit or a considerably lower profit (30% -50% of market value).  I don't consider it a business or a money making scheme but I want to know if HMRC would before I find another place and go bankrupt after I get a huge unexpected bill from them!  For those years I shared my house would I be liable for capital gains tax?

I've owned the property for 7 1/2 years, I would say I've been on my own for about three years, one lodger for about two years and three lodgers for about two years.  During the period of lodgers I lived there on and off (mostly lived there though) and I have always considered it my only home with all my things and mail going there (I haven't rented anywhere else).  I would share when I had friends who needed somehwere to stay or when I have travelled for work purposes and two two month backpacking holidays.

*It feels ludicrous if I had to pay because I would have been paying CGT for the only privilege of sharing my house!*

Comment: Are you selling the home now? Was it your primary residence at the same time as your friends were living in it?

Comment: yes, I'm planning on selling it.  It has always been my primary residence as I've always had a room just for me and nobody else but sometimes I've let people stay there, taken some nominal rent and been travelling or working outside of the area on contracts / a little bit of short back packing too

Comment: I've owned the property for 7 1/2 years, I would say I've been on my own for about three years, one lodger for about two years and three lodgers for about two years.  The lodgers were always my friends though and over all this time paid around 30% of market value, sometimes 50% actually but I have only sometimes made a profit after the rent a room scheme and then that has never covered the time I have spent repairing and organising things for them and after them.

Comment: Did you claim the rent on your tax return each year?

Comment: In all but two cases any money I received I declared it, even if it was just them paying me bills.  One case I didn't declare anything, they stayed with me entirely rent free but they were on the electoral roll and the council tax bill (even though they didn't pay!)  The other case they didn't pay for anything nor were on any official documents (I might forget about that one!)

Comment: I don't quite understand the premises of the question.  Is capital gains tax assessed on a yearly basis in the UK? Or, is it assessed only at the time of sale of the property but is deemed to have accrued (in annual increments?) over the period during which the property was held, and the OP thinks that there should have been no accrual at all (indeed the accrual should be forgiven, thereby reducing the tax due) during the time that the OP was renting out parts of his flat at lower than market rates to friends?

Comment: @DilipSarwate The latter. CGT is not payable on your primary residence but if a property was only your primary residence for part of the time you owned it, CGT is payable when sold on the periods for which it wasn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll be liable for CGT for any period when you had more than one lodger. The amount of rent you charged them and whether or not it was a market rent are irrelevant. Use the HMRC web site to work out your liability [here](https://www.gov.uk/tax-relief-selling-home/y).

Comment: it is as simple as that then, just the number of lodgers...not about the profit or the intention?  Crazy, so I get taxed a high amount just because I share something.  What if they only paid the bills?

Comment: @orangesherbert Income tax is the tax you pay on rental profits, and the profit that you make is very relevant to your income tax bill.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I asked a follow up question, basically is there any difference between a friend staying a couple of months and a lodger!  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107465/capital-gains-tax-if-i-have-two-friends-living-in-my-house-and-they-only-pay-b

Comment: @orangesherbert As far as I know, if they weren’t paying rent then you weren’t renting out part of the property. But I’d check that with HMRC.